# Any way to write one sub/function with two possible incoming data types

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, methods, overloading

I am working in Visual Studio 2015 with VB.Net. I know of overloading a sub/function and that may be the answer to my question, but I'm wondering if there is a more concise way to handle this.

I am doing some game design testing and I have made two classes, both sharing some variables of the same type. (HP, MP, Attack, Defense, etc.) I will have a sub that will take in a player and modify some of those stats. I will also have the same sub for an enemy class. The subs will be exactly the same, line for line since they are working on the shared stats.

My overall question is rather than writing one sub for modifying these for the player class and then overloading that by copying it and changing the incoming variable type to enemy, is there a way to write the sub once and in the header indicate that two different types can come in but only one should be accepted?

Right now my headers look like this

```
Sub round(ByRef x as player)

Sub round(ByRef x as enemy)
```

Is there a way to just have one sub with a header like

```
Sub round(ByRef x as player Or enemy)
```

I've tried the above code and it doesn't work. I'm not even sure this is possible. Is my best bet just to overload the subs? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could declare the parameter as object

Comment: @DIe Hmm, pretty crude compared to using OO inheritance or interfaces which would provide a cleaner API.

Comment: You mentioned each of those classes require some of the same parameters and functions. This is a textbook example of where inheritance can be useful. Might by helpful to make a character class that has the HP, MP, Attack, etc and have your method be part of that base class as well. Then player and enemy can inherit that class, and share some of their logic for common functionalities

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using ByRef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention the subs will be identical - and that your player and enemy classes have (some) identical properties which they both share. This sounds like an ideal case for these classes to either

1. inherit from some base type (e.g. "GameCharacter" or something) which provides the shared properties,

or perhaps

2. both implement an interface which defines these properties.

Which is more appropriate will probably depend on your exact circumstances, but in either case you then have simply to accept an instance of the base class / interface type into your Sub, and then you only need one copy of it, e.g.

```
Sub round(ByRef x As GameCharacter) 'base class
```

or

```
Sub round(ByRef x As IGameCharacter) 'interface definition
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of inheritance. Your suggestion prompted me to reevaluate my code for those classes and it looks like a sub class that those two will inherit is going to be a great improvement on my code. Thanks!